# Button does not work if its on the same line as a h1

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, web-applications

So I want my page title and profile button to be on the same line (header of each page). However, the button does not work when it's on the same line and works when on different lines.

```
    return (
        <div className='Master-div'>
            <Sidebar />
            <div className='contacts'>
                <div className='header-dashboard'>
                    <h1>Dashboard</h1>
                    <ProfileButton></ProfileButton> /*this does not work*/
                </div>
                <div><ProfileButton></ProfileButton></div> /*this works*/
                <div className='line'></div>
                <div className='contents'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Dashboard

.header-dashboard{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

I have tried making different divs and putting them on the same line using CSS but that doesn't work either. I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Try `<ProfileButton />` since you're not passing in any data or children. But there doesn't seem to be any difference between those lines.

Answer (score 1):

Default h1 element style is `display:block`.

If you give it manually as inline, then they will appear next to each other.

```
h1 style="display: inline"
```

Comment: Thanks! just figured that I had an overlapping line just underneath the div, hence the buttons were not working! Thanks for your response though!